# CSOM: How do I loop through Files in a Folder and get the data from associated List columns?

Tags: development, csom

I'm new to the Sharepoint client object model and I'm having difficulty getting all of the items from a particular `List` along with their column data. I think it's confusing me because it's actually a `Folder` set to display as a `List` which is then filtered by a `View`!

The setup is like this:

**List**: Managed Collateral
**View**: Proposal Collateral
**Folder**: Proposal Collateral
**Folder relative URL**: /sites/collateral/Managed Collateral/Proposal Collateral

Which looks like this:

[image]

I can use methods like `Lists.GetByTitle("title");` and `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("path");` to get the `List` and `Folder` objects respectively. I get the correct `Count` returned from these so I think they're returned correctly.

I've tried iterating through these but I can only ever seem to access static properties like `file.Name` and `file.TimeLastModified`, but my list shows columns like `Content_x0020_Type` and `Proposal_x0020_Type`.
I've tried things like `file["Content_x0020_Type"]` but that didn't work for me either.

**How do I get a Folder, then loop through each item and get the data from the columns from the associated List/View?**

I can post my code if needed, but I felt it would just confuse matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know when you've had an issue for two days and you've read countless bits of documentation and forum posts before finally posting a question somewhere only to work it out shortly after? Yeah, that.

Anyway, I think I have something that fetches the data I want in the most efficient way. I'll post it here rather than delete my question in case it helps someone else.

If anyone has any improvements or suggestions then I might change the accepted answer.

```
// Fields
private static string _siteUrl;
private static string _userName;
private static string _passWord;
private static string _domain;

private static DataTable dataTable;

private ClientContext _clientContext;
private Web _spWebsite;

// We'll store the data in a table for ease
dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Path", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Proposal Grouping", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Modified", typeof(DateTime));

_clientContext = new ClientContext(_siteUrl);
_clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _passWord, _domain);
_spWebsite = _clientContext.Web;

List list = _spWebsite.Lists.GetByTitle(@"Managed Collateral");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View><Query></Query></View>";
camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = @"/sites/collateral/Managed Collateral/Proposal Collateral";

ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

_clientContext.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(
    item => item.File.Name,
    item => item.File.ServerRelativeUrl,
    item => item["Proposal_x0020_Navigation_x0020_Grouping"],
    item => item["Modified"]));

_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

if (listItems != null)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
    {
        DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = item.File.Name;
        dr["Path"] = item.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
        dr["Proposal Grouping"] = item["Proposal_x0020_Navigation_x0020_Grouping"];
        dr["Modified"] = item["Modified"];
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}

dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```